# How does sscanf work? (in assembly)

Tags: assembly, stack, scanf

I'm in the process of trying to decode some assembly code generated from a binary.  There's a call to the `sscanf` function in the code:

```
 400f08:       e8 13 fc ff ff          callq  400b20 <sscanf@plt>
 400f0d:       89 45 fc                mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
```

Can you tell me how `sscanf` works in assembly?  I'm pretty sure the number of arguments is stored in `%eax`....does it push the input into the stack in reverse order?  So say my input is `0 1`, after running sscanf, `%eax`=2 and the stack looks like:

```
1
0  <----%rsp (top of the stack)
```

Is this correct?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the calling convention of the platform, as normal. 32-bit Linux uses cdecl by default, which has you push all the arguments onto the stack in reverse order. 64-bit Linux uses the System V AMD64 ABI convention, which uses `RDI`, `RSI`, `RDX`, `RCX`, `R8`, and `R9` for integers and address and the XMM registers for floating point arguments (with surplus arguments going on the stack).

The number of arguments isn't pushed anywhere; AFAIK `sscanf` determines this from the format string (though I'm happy to be corrected). The System V AMD64 ABI (64-bit) does specify that `AL` is used to store the number of XMM registers used (from 0 to 8), but that applies to floating-point arguments only (which should never be arguments to `sscanf`).

Answer (score 2):

`sscanf` takes as arguments a string to scan, a format string, and **pointers** to variables where to store the results of the scan. So, your 0 and 1 numbers would be stored on the corresponding variables, assuming the scan was successful.

`EAX` contains the return value. The `*scanf` family of functions return the number of elements scanned successfully, so you can know if the scan was successful, and how successful it was.